# Only Content Controls Allowed directly issue when Deployed via VS2015

Tags: page-layout

Interesting issue.  I am creating Page Layouts in Visual Studio 2015 for SharePoint 2016 (with Visual Studio Tools preview 2) and when I deploy the solution in Visual Studio and create a page, I get the "Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls."

But when I upload the .aspx file directly into the Masterpage Gallery, it works fine.  What could be the issue?

Bismarck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many times the cause is improper case for the `<asp:Content>`.

1. Make sure you have used `<asp:Content>` instead of `<asp:content>`.
2. Also check your `<asp:Content>` has correct ContentPlaceHolderID.
3. Check there are no white spaces around `<asp:Content>`.